# how to use images in apex-chart markers?

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I'm using a line chart in apex-charts and I was asked for a slightly different update. For this update I need to place images or text inside the markers but I didn't find anything about it in the documentation, is there any fill property that does this or alternatives to do it?

I've already tried applying direct functions and it didn't go well.
Then I tried to suppose properties inside the markers( fill, fillImage) but I didn't see any results